# PathBindable For Multiple Path Parameters In Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I read [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders) doc on PathBindable.

If I have a route like this:

```
GET     /user/:user/posts/:postId            controllers.BinderApplication.post(user: scalaguide.binder.models.Post)
```

How would I be able to capture both parameters in the Post object.

The post class would look something like this

```
case class Post(postId: Long, userId: Long)
```

I know that I can use [QueryStringBindable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#querystringbindable), but I'm wondering if there's a way to use path parameters as well.

Comment: The simplest solution is for the `controllers.BinderApplication.post` method to accept two parameters that correspond with the path parameters, `:user` and `:postId`. Then in the body of the corresponding controller method you can create an instance of your `Post` class using those values.

Comment: You're probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, good practice will be an action composition or just an action.

routes:

```
GET     /user/:userId/posts/:postId   controllers.HomeController.post(userId: Long, postId: Long)
```

controller:

```
def post (postId: Long, userId: Long) = Action{
  val user = Post(postId, userId) //some massive operation, could be async, then use Action.async
  Ok(user.toString())
}
```

To construct `Post`, you will need to get user and the post id; it seems like a pretty massive operation.  Play bind routes on the IO thread, so you are going to block all requests by doing a massive operation in this place.

[Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders):

> In this example findById method is invoked to retrieve User instance;
>   note that in real world such method should be lightweight and not
>   involve e.g. DB access, because the code is called on the server IO
>   thread and must be totally non-blocking.
>
> You would therefore for example use simple objects identifier as path
>   bindable, and retrieve the real values using action composition.

And some thread with advice from Greg Methvin (Lightbend engineer): https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/play-framework/b1fF2EdmCJ8/F2mX1EflJAAJ

Still, if you want to do such trick, you can use [String Interpolating Routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSirdRouter)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the String Interpolation doc